# ValueError: Trying to share variable in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn, but seeing dimension mismatch

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to use tensorflow to make an unrolled RNN model and seeing error message that I don't understand. Ultimately, trying to do a simple time series prediction with multi-step lookahead where the input vector is a set of samples of lookback windows (each 10 steps long, 1 feature each) and the response set samples are the next (5) steps of the series for each 10-step lookback window.

Here you can see the dimensions of the data sets and the intended RNN cell neurons

```py
n_samples = int( data_x.get_shape()[0] )
n_input_steps = int( data__x.get_shape()[1] )
n_inputs = int( tx.get_shape()[2] )
n_neurons = 7 # small for demo purposes
n_output_steps = int( data_y.get_shape()[1] )
n_outputs = int( data_y.get_shape()[2] )

print (n_samples, n_input_steps, n_inputs, n_neurons, n_output_steps, n_outputs)

#output
(97, 10, 1, 7, 5, 1)
```

and the unrolled model code

```py
# params section

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, n_input_steps, n_inputs])
print X.get_shape()
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, n_output_steps, n_outputs])
print y.get_shape()

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(name='basic_lstm_cell', num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu, use_peepholes=True)
# wrap in fully connect single output projection
fc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_size=n_outputs, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=fc_cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float64)

"""
expecting unrolled RNN:

y[0]   .... y[n_input_steps]
 |           |
 * -> ... -> *
 |     ....  |
x[0]        x[n_input_steps] 

where each * is an RNN cell with a single output
"""
```

The full error message being thrown when trying to set up this RNN looks like

```py
(?, 10, 1)
(?, 5, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-204-d52a40d9a302> in <module>()
     10 fc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_size=n_outputs, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
     11 
---> 12 outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=fc_cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float64)
     13 
....
....
....
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in _get_single_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, partition_info, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, validate_shape, use_resource, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
    864         raise ValueError("Trying to share variable %s, but specified shape %s"
    865                          " and found shape %s." % (name, shape,
--> 866                                                    found_var.get_shape()))
    867       if not dtype.is_compatible_with(found_var.dtype):
    868         dtype_str = dtype.name

ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/output_projection_wrapper/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (8, 28) and found shape (4, 12).
```

What are these numbers in the ValueError? Having hard time figuring out how these are being derived, so hard to debug what is going wrong upstream. Is there something fundamentally wrong with how I'm setting this up? Eg. rather than having data_x's shape be (?, 10, 1) and data_y's be (?, 5, 1), should data_y's shape be (?, 10, 1) to match x's (where each sample in data_y is just the corresponding series in data_x shifted up by 5 steps)?

Would appreciate any debugging advice or fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some random tinkering, found that changing the cell creation snippet of the code to

```py
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(
    name='basic_lstm_cell', num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
# wrap cell in fully connect single output projection
fc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_size=n_outputs, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
```

(mainly removing `use_peepholes=True`) seemed to prevent the error from appearing (should note that I never really knew what peepholes where in the first place and just kept them there when some snippet of code, but they appear to have affected the dimensions somewhere). Will need to do more research to explain how exactly this affected the code.